# Is there a way to view past cordova (android) builds?

Tags: android, cordova, keystore, android-keystore

Long story short, I screwed up by being a cordova noob and not realising that `cordova build` overwrites your existing files whenever you run it. I left my keystore file in `projectroot/platforms/android/ant_build` and thought that it was a safe place to leave the keystore file at that time. Oh hell no it wasn't.

Have tried some Mac recovery software but I couldn't recover my keystore file. If there are other suggestions I would gladly try them out too. Thank you.

Comment: I m not sure if this will work. Do you have a copy of the APK file of the previous build installed on you Physical mobile device? If yes you could extract the `APK` file from the mobile and then UNZIP the `APK` to get hold of the `Key` file.

Comment: Really?? Is there a guide for doing that?

Comment: But I can't locate that APK... overwritten together with all the other stuff :/